# Why the global variable remain the same after calling a function to increase it?

Tags: javascript

Why the global variable is still 5 after calling the increment function? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<script>
function increment(val) {
  val+=1;
}

var val = 5;

increment(val); 

alert(val);

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function increment(val) {
  val+=1;
}
```

declares a variable `val` local to your function. You change your local variable and not the external one. It's the same as

```
function increment(val2) {
  val2+=1;
}
```

You could do this :

```
function increment(val) {
  return val+1;
}
var val=5;
val = increment(val);
```

or

```
function increment(holder, varname) {
  holder[varname] = holder[varname]+1;
}
var val=5;
increment(window, 'val');
```

Comment: It's a global variable, so not passing anything and using the global directly inside the function is also an option.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes, but I guess there would be no point in the function then, that's why I didn't propose it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because primitive variables in Javascript are passed **by value, not by reference**.

> When passing in a primitive type variable like a string or a number,
>   the value is passed in by value. This means that any changes to that
>   variable while in the function are completely separate from anything
>   that happens outside the function

Check this great blog entry for more info on this subject:
http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the global vars.
When you pass the argument to a function, its creating a local copy of the valriable. So if you want to effect the global variable from the function, you don't pass it when calling the function, because you can anyway access the global variable, without passing.

```
<script>
function increment() {
  val+=1;
}

var val = 5;

increment(); 

alert(val);
```

Notice that when you are defining the `increment()` function you have specified the parameter as `**val**`. So inside the function every reference to `val` is for this local argument. If you want to access the actuall global variable use `window.val`.